# How can I pre-compress files with mod_deflate in Apache 2.x?

Tags: apache, http, gzip, mod-deflate, content-encoding

I am serving all content through apache with `Content-Encoding: zip` but that compresses on the fly.  A good amount of my content is static files on the disk.  I want to gzip the files beforehand rather than compressing them every time they are requested.

This is something that, I believe, `mod_gzip` did in Apache 1.x automatically, but just having the file with .gz next to it.  That's no longer the case with `mod_deflate`.

Comment: I don't think you're going to save much though; with modern web servers, the cost of compressing the content on the fly is negligible.

Comment: I'm running the web server in a Xen VM so I'd like to conserve as much CPU as possible for the other VMs.  

Also I was able to double the request rate measured with httperf on a pre-compressed 55k file compared to compressing on the fly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076752/how-to-force-apache-to-use-manually-pre-compressed-gz-file-of-css-and-js-files?lq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This functionality was misplaced in mod_gzip anyway. In Apache 2.x, [you do that with content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). Specifically, you need to enable `MultiViews` with the [`Options` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) and you need to specify your encoding types with the [`AddEncoding` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addencoding).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076752/how-to-force-apache-to-use-manually-pre-compressed-gz-file-of-css-and-js-files?lq=1

Answer (score 8):

To answer my own question with the really simple line I was missing in my confiuration:

```
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

I was missing the MultiViews option.  It's there in the Ubuntu default web server configuration, so don't be like me and drop it off.

Also I wrote a quick Rake task to compress all the files.

```
namespace :static do
    desc "Gzip compress the static content so Apache doesn't need to do it on-the-fly."
    task :compress do
        puts "Gzipping js, html and css files."
        Dir.glob("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/**/*.{js,html,css}") do |file|
            system "gzip -c -9 #{file} > #{file}.gz"
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to serve pre-compressed files using `mod_negotiation` although it is a bit finicky.  The primary difficulty is that **[only requests for files which do not exist are negotiated](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)**.  So if `foo.js` and `foo.js.gz` both exist, responses for `/foo.js` will always be uncompressed (although responses for `/foo` would work correctly).

The easiest solution I've found ([from François Marier](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/serving-pre-compressed-files-using/)) is to rename uncompressed files with a double file extension, so `foo.js` is deployed as `foo.js.js` so requests for `/foo.js` negotiate between `foo.js.js` (no encoding) and `foo.js.gz` (gzip encoding).

I combine that trick with the following configuration:

```
Options +MultiViews
RemoveType .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gz

# Send .tar.gz without Content-Encoding: gzip
<FilesMatch ".+\.tar\.gz$">
    RemoveEncoding .gz
    # Note:  Can use application/x-gzip for backwards-compatibility
    AddType application/gzip .gz
</FilesMatch>
```

I [wrote a post](https://kevinlocke.name/bits/2016/01/20/serving-pre-compressed-files-with-apache-multiviews/) which discusses the reasoning for this configuration and some alternatives in detail.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more. With Apache 2.4.25 I always get uncompressed results, probably becuase the MultiViews only kicks in if the file doesn't exist as named. The doc says as much. Pity!

Comment: Good catch @MvG, you are absolutely right!  I've updated the answer with a workaround, although it is not ideal as it requires renaming the uncompressed file and a bit of configuration trickery.  Hope it helps!

Comment: @Kevinoid: That's exactly the workaround I came up with myself, after sleeping on it. Nice!

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid MultiViews will not work as expected: the doc says Multiviews works "if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist...", in other words: if you have a file foo.js and foo.js.gz in the same directory, just activating MultiViews will not cause the .gz file to be sent even if the AcceptEncoding gzip header is transmitted by the browser (you can verify this behavior by temporarily disabling mod_deflate and monitoring the response with e.g. HTTPFox).

I am not sure if there is a way around this with MultiViews (maybe you can rename the original file and then add a special AddEncoding directive), but I believe you can construct a mod_rewrite rule to handle this.

Comment: I'm sure it worked at the time, and I'm sure I didn't delete the original files.  It's plausible mod_rewrite was involved, somehow.  I probably had a rule that was "serve this statically if the file exists".  I may have changed it to include the .gz extension, but I no longer have access to that system to verify.

Comment: If in your example you request just foo rather than foo.js, it will work. If the client accepts gzip they will get foo.js.gz else they will get foo.js.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076752/how-to-force-apache-to-use-manually-pre-compressed-gz-file-of-css-and-js-files?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

I have an Apache 2 built from source, and I found I had to modify the following in my **httpd.conf** file:

Add MultiViews to Options:

> ```
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
> ```

Uncomment AddEncoding:

> ```
> AddEncoding x-compress .Z
> AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
> ```

Comment AddType:

> ```
> #AddType application/x-compress .Z
> #AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
> ```

Answer (score 1):

mod_gzip compressed content on the fly as well. You can pre-compress the files by actually logging into your server, and doing it from shell.

```
cd /var/www/.../data/
for file in *; do
    gzip -c $file > $file.gz;
done;
```

Comment: This will remove the original files, which means clients that don't have Aceept-Encoding: gzip won't be serviced.

Comment: While you're editing, why not add -9 and get the highest compression possible.  My 1500 files compressed in 38 seconds, so it's worth doing to save every byte possible in bandwidth and download time. :)

(Also wishing I could edit my typo in my previous comment.  Ugh)

Comment: Not according to the man page on my Mac, it says -6 is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mod_cache`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html) to proxy local content in memory or on disk. I don't know if this will work as expected with `mod_deflate`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of big .json files. Most readers are in this situation. The preview answers didn't talk about the returned "Content-type".

I you want the following request return a pre-compressed file with "Content-Type: application/json" transparently, use Multiview with ForceType

```
http://www.domain.com/(...)/bigfile.json
-> Content-Encoding:gzip, Content-Type: Content-Encoding:gzip
```

1) files must be rename: "file.ext.ext"

2) Multiview works great with ForceType

In the file system:

```
// Note there is no bigfile.json
(...)/bigfile.json.gz
(...)/bigfile.json.json
```

In your apache config:

```
<Directory (...)>
    AddEncoding gzip .gz
    Options +Multiviews
    <Files *.json.gz>
        ForceType application/json
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Short and simple :)