# gzipping a minified .js file

Tags: javascript, gzip, minify

I've minified a .js file, and everything is just fine. But, when I gzip, the browser no longer executes the file. What am I doing wrong? Here's the gzip command:

```
> gzip test.js
```

Which results in a regular gzip file called test.js.gz. Do I need to include something in the .js, or pass an added argument to gzip so the browser interprets the file correctly? I tested this with both Chrome and FF.

Thank you advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a client side problem.

Your web *server* has to be configured to recognise the gzipped file, and send the appropriate `Content-Encoding: gzip` header to tell the browser to expect gzipped data.

Comment: Know any links that explain how to do that with apache?

Comment: Look for `mod_deflate` which I believe does on-the-fly compression. I'm not sure what the preferred method is for pre-compressed data.

Comment: ah, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75482/how-can-i-pre-compress-files-with-mod-deflate-in-apache-2-x

Comment: +1 Great answer (including comment for `mod_deflate`). Thanks a lot!