# Apache 2.x mod_deflate compression only working on OSX

Tags: apache, compression, gzip, mod-deflate

Apache2 successfully streams pre-compressed content on my Mac's installation.  I can use files like index.gz, textfile.gz, etc and they all load fine in a browser.

But when I try to create the same configuration on other Apache environments like Ubuntu and CentOS installs, the gzip content never renders in the browser; it's always downloaded as a file.

It's the AddEncoding directive config that succeeded in streaming files from the OSX Apache install, specifically the changes recommended here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/609051/1074464.  If I turn off those directives, it will fail and defer to downloading again.  As in that example, the OSX install uses /etc/apache2/httpd.conf for these directives, but the other distros use /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and its many includes of the virtual hosts sub files.  I've made the AddType and AddEncoding updates in about every location I can think of including:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/apache/mods-enabled/mime.conf
```

As you can see from the shotgun troubleshoot approach I'm not clear on where/if/in what order I need to specify these directives.  I thought I'd covered all possible locations, but maybe there is another or perhaps a directive I'm not seeing on the Linux systems is stepping on the ones I've configured?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

After comparing the working and non-working installs on virtually a file-by-file basis, I found this entry in the broken Linux install's /etc/mime.types:

```
application/x-gzip              gz
```

Commenting resolved the issue.