# PHP performance: gzcompress() vs ob_start('ob_gzhandler')

Tags: php, performance, caching, gzip

I'm wondering, how to compress my output best.

Usually I just add `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` at the top of my `index.php`, to compress the whole output.

I'm using a simple caching-Class to store the generated HTML in a file (`index.cache.htm`) instead of rebuilding it on every refresh. The content of `index.cache.htm` is minified due to a better performance.

Couldn't I compress the cached content instead of using `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')`?

**Example 1** (caching the buffered output):

```
ob_start();                               // start buffer
$b = ob_get_contents();                   // get buffer
ob_end_clean();                           // free buffer

$b = CustomHTMLMinifyFunction($b);        // minify the HTML
$b = gzcompress($b);                      // compress the HTML
file_put_contents('index.cache.htm', $b); // save file
```

**Example 2** (caching explicit data):

```
$d = 'Some data, e.g. JSON';              // some data
$d = gzcompress($d);                      // compress data
file_put_contents('data.cache.txt', $d);  // save file
```

What's the difference or best practise? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: Does it ever make sense to store the compressed data in a file? Or is it only useful while outputting the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ob_start`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

> The *[callback]* function will be called when the output buffer is flushed (sent) or cleaned (with `ob_flush()`, `ob_clean()` or similar function) or when the output buffer is flushed to the browser at the end of the request.

In other words, `ob_get_contents()` will return the output buffer uncompressed contents:

```
$log = 0;

function callback($input){
    global $log;
    $log += 1;
    return ob_gzhandler($input);
}

ob_start('callback');
$ob = ob_get_contents();

echo $log; // echoes 0, callback function was not called
```

You must compress the output of `ob_get_contents()` if you want to cache a compressed version of the output data.

But you must configure your web server so that it is aware the files are pre-compressed ([instructions for Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75482/1446005)). You can't just send compressed files to your client without [setting proper headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

To answer your edit, it makes sense to pre-compress your cache, otherwise the content is compressed on the fly. Also keep in mind that some clients do not support compression: you should keep an uncompressed version of your files if you want to be able to serve them.